# Size of individual folders in svn

Tags: svn, size, directory

How can i find the size of the folders in svn individually. Is there a way to limit the size of the folders?Say in case I have 10 folders, can I limit their size so that people using it have a limited space?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean inside the repository? If this is the case you can't limit the size inside the repository. There do not exist any kind of mechanism for this. What you can limit of course is the size of the whole repository.